# Front Vent Always On Regardless of Vent Setting 1997 Civic LX

Tags: civic, vents

My 1997 Civic LX has an issue where no matter the vent setting (feet only, defrost/feet, defrost only) the front vents are always blowing. I'm not talking about the little vents either that point to the driver/passenger door glass but the actual four outter and inner vents. When switching to non-front vent modes I do get what I select but it's always in addition to the front vents. I'm assuming it's a bad connection or board somewhere under the dash. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake as I double checked the operation of the vents and it turns out the middle vents do turn off when they're supposed to. I was under the impression the outter vents would turn off as well but they don't as they're tied directly to the mini-vents that point towards the driver or passenger window. I just closed the outer vents to direct more flow to the mini-vents. Thanks for the details though as maybe it may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The vents are operated by cables which are connected to the lever controls behind the dash. They can become dis-connected at thier ends. A simple refit of the cable(s) may be all is required.